# Custom module block programmatically assigning it to a specific role

Tags: blocks

I have a Custom module that implements a block how do I programmatically assign it to a specific role or roles in drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
function _<module-name>_check_user_access() {
  $roles = [
    'editor',
    'admin',
  ];


  $current_role = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  foreach($roles as $role) {
    if($role == $current_role[1]) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

See my blog post for more information [about it](http://purencool.com/how-to-assign-content-to-a-specific-user-role-drupal-8-in-a-custom-module-programmatically)